# Unity and onGameReady not defined

Tags: airconsole

This is based off of the Air Console demo from github.

I compiled the "basic" example for web (no alterations), and set it up locally, and ran with the Simlulator syntax from teh website.

The controllers load properly, but the screen does not.

It has several errors when ran:

```
(program):1 Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://MACHINENAME" from accessing a frame with origin "http://www.airconsole.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.
```

and also:

```html
exception thrown: ReferenceError: onGameReady is not defined,ReferenceError: onGameReady is not defined
    at eval (eval at _JS_Eval_EvalJS (http://MACHINENAME/unity/Release/build-webgl.js:1:156420), <anonymous>:1:1)
    at eval (native)
    at _JS_Eval_EvalJS (http://MACHINENAME/unity/Release/build-webgl.js:1:156420)
    at Array.WRb (http://MACHINENAME/unity/Release/build-webgl.js:16:784695)
    at YKk (http://MACHINENAME/unity/Release/build-webgl.js:7:594173)
    at WKk (http://MACHINENAME/unity/Release/build-webgl.js:7:593680)
    at Array.Rpf (http://MACHINENAME/unity/Release/build-webgl.js:9:667389)
    at Array.Lwm (http://MACHINENAME/unity/Release/build-webgl.js:8:87554)
    at Object.zIn [as dynCall_iiii] (http://MACHINENAME/unity/Release/build-webgl.js:29:39143)
    at invoke_iiii (http://MACHINENAME/unity/Release/build-webgl.js:1:356104)Module.printErr @ screen.html:34
UnityConfig.js:76 Invoking error handler due to
Uncaught ReferenceError: onGameReady is not defined
```

Comment: I'd guess that some security settings of your browser block communication, which prevents loading and leads to those errors

Comment: It looks like I had the default webgl template selected, which was causing the problem.

After it was switched to the Air Console one, it works.  I did need to clear my cache when reloading it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OnGameReady method is defined in the WebGL Templates folder included in the Unity Plugin.
Make sure to import and keep the entire WebGL Templates folder in your project.